# Rails Date.today shows wrong day on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4

I have an app which shows events in a calendar and the current date is highlighted on the calendar. I followed Railcasts calendar (revised) episode. In the helper method, you set the current date using

```
Date.today
```

this works on the local machine but when deployed to Heroku it's the day ahead of today. So for today, October 31 is being highlighted not October 30.

Does anyone know the issue here? I've tried changing a few things like

```
config.time_zone = 'Central Time (US & Canada)'
```

in my application.rb file but nothing has worked. any suggestions??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set it via a config variable eg;

```
heroku config:add TZ=Europe/London
```

Answer (score 1):

```
We have to set the timezone configuration at **environment.rb** file.

#app/config/environment.rb

config.time_zone = "Pacific Time (US & Canada)"
```

Comment: Not sure if you were on a different version.
My 4.0 is at #app/config/appliction.rb